# Why don't monkey-patched methods get passed a reference to the instance?

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, self, monkeypatching

See this example for a demonstration:

```
>>> class M:
       def __init__(self): self.x = 4
>>> sample = M()
>>> def test(self):
        print(self.x)
>>> sample.test = test
>>> sample.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    sample.test()
TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `test` method you are assigning to `sample.test` is not bound to the `sample` object. You need to manually bind it like this

```
import types
sample.test = types.MethodType(test, sample)
sample.test()
# 4
```

Comment: Is this behavior limited to py3k?

Comment: @BrianCain Nope. It is the same in Python 2.x also

Comment: Or use the function as a descriptor directly: `sample.test = test.__get__(sample)`. Source link: [`func_descr_get`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Objects/funcobject.c#l645)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are objects like any other and there needs to be consistency on what happens when objects are assigned to names, regardless of where the names are (i.e. in local namespace or on as attributes on an object).

When you define a function with `def` you are binding a function to the name after `def`, and when you do assignment like `some_object.f = my_function` you are also binding the function to a name.  There's no magic in the assignment process that would change the nature of the function.

There *is* magic in the class definition process.  Functions defined as instance methods (that is, functions defined inside a class definition) are not simply assigned as attributes to instances, but instead they are bound to the instance using a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).